# jmeter extracted variables are not session related

Tags: jmeter

I am testing a webpage which has a security.token for each new login. My approach was to extract the token from the response using RegExp and replace all security.token with ${token}. This works fine when there is only one concurrent user. The problem is that when there are multiple users, the extracted ${token} doesn't work for every users and the test broke.

Any suggestion or solution?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Well-behaved JMeter test should send different requests for different virtual users. Exact configuration may vary depending on the application under test implementation details, however some common practices exist.

I believe if you add a [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan your issue should go away.

Also consider following recommendations from the [How To Make JMeter Behave More Like A Real Browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) article to mimic real users with virtual with 100% match